# Text wrap around image, to one column

Tags: html, css, image, text

I have an image I want text to wrap around, but at about 793px I want it to just drop down to one column, image on top, text on bottom. I tried a media query with float: none, but for some reason that didn't work. Thanks in advance!

```css
/*float left*/ .left { float: left; /*left in our text*/ margin: 3px; /*space around the image*/ 
}

@media (max-width: 793px;) {
 img {
  
        float:none;

 }

}
```

```html
<p> <img src="https://36.media.tumblr.com/e09631b272ecaf21862513edd536eeed/tumblr_n7a2ldALJt1so5delo1_500.jpg" alt="temp" class="left" /> Lorem "ipsum" dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.

   Maecenas tempor finibus hendrerit. Aenean rutrum rhoncus ultricies. Vivamus egestas sollicitudin ex pulvinar finibus. Suspendisse a mi ac augue dictum blandit. Donec malesuada convallis placerat. Integer et hendrerit tellus. Donec eu justo mattis, consectetur orci ac, posuere diam. Integer nec accumsan turpis. Ut quis dolor eu ante pulvinar iaculis cursus at quam.

   Donec laoreet facilisis sapien euismod finibus. Nam malesuada dapibus ex, sed rutrum tortor consequat in. Aenean quis elit dapibus, vestibulum massa nec, porta odio. Nam accumsan est sed velit scelerisque commodo. Morbi id massa quis lorem tristique convallis at vel leo. Aenean pharetra aliquam porta. Sed ac tellus rutrum, egestas leo sed, sagittis velit. Vestibulum et tellus arcu.

   Suspendisse imperdiet purus felis, at pharetra magna molestie at. Aenean non nibh sed ex laoreet tempor vel vel dui. Fusce ut arcu eget mi pulvinar molestie a ut metus. Etiam ex ante, volutpat ac leo convallis, venenatis sollicitudin lorem. Mauris tempor mollis euismod. Phasellus viverra dolor egestas turpis pulvinar, ac sollicitudin arcu facilisis. Sed viverra quam lectus, in fermentum libero vestibulum ac. Duis fringilla tempus dui, lobortis fringilla lacus volutpat quis. Nam iaculis nisl vitae mauris scelerisque, eget vulputate purus aliquet. Nullam dictum nunc a enim tempus, et fermentum lectus tristique.

   Nulla quis mattis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a elit nec ipsum accumsan cursus. Nunc vitae lorem a tellus aliquam luctus eu eget turpis. Vivamus dapibus elementum imperdiet. Nullam facilisis mauris ac tellus fringilla volutpat. Sed elementum ligula dolor, vitae tincidunt ligula ultrices in.
   </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're having issues is that images are inline by default, so we need to add `display: block` to the image in the media query. Also your media query is missing some components.

CSS:

```
img{
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 793px){
  img{
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto 15px;
  }
}
```

That should do the trick. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erwstout/5kfrg5vp/1/).

**UPDATE**
Centered the image with some margin as well updated fiddle and code.

Comment: That did work, thank you! Do you know how I can't get rid of the ugly extra space right after break down though? The text is centered, but the image is not . . .

Comment: You would have to center the image using `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a million!

Answer (score -1):

I think the other answer works perfectly well. I was actually struggling with your bug when I realized one of the problems was that your media query wasn't formatted correctly. The semi-colon was messing things up. Anyways, happy coding!

```css
img { 
    float: left;
    margin: 3px;
}

@media (max-width: 793px) {
 p {
        float: left;
 }

}
```

```html
<img src="https://36.media.tumblr.com/e09631b272ecaf21862513edd536eeed/tumblr_n7a2ldALJt1so5delo1_500.jpg" alt="temp"/> 

<p>Lorem "ipsum" dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
Maecenas tempor finibus hendrerit. Aenean rutrum rhoncus ultricies. Vivamus egestas sollicitudin ex pulvinar finibus. Suspendisse a mi ac augue dictum blandit. Donec malesuada convallis placerat. Integer et hendrerit tellus. Donec eu justo mattis, consectetur orci ac, posuere diam. Integer nec accumsan turpis. Ut quis dolor eu ante pulvinar iaculis cursus at quam.
Donec laoreet facilisis sapien euismod finibus. Nam malesuada dapibus ex, sed rutrum tortor consequat in. Aenean quis elit dapibus, vestibulum massa nec, porta odio. Nam accumsan est sed velit scelerisque commodo. Morbi id massa quis lorem tristique convallis at vel leo. Aenean pharetra aliquam porta. Sed ac tellus rutrum, egestas leo sed, sagittis velit. Vestibulum et tellus arcu.
Suspendisse imperdiet purus felis, at pharetra magna molestie at. Aenean non nibh sed ex laoreet tempor vel vel dui. Fusce ut arcu eget mi pulvinar molestie a ut metus. Etiam ex ante, volutpat ac leo convallis, venenatis sollicitudin lorem. Mauris tempor mollis euismod. Phasellus viverra dolor egestas turpis pulvinar, ac sollicitudin arcu facilisis. Sed viverra quam lectus, in fermentum libero vestibulum ac. Duis fringilla tempus dui, lobortis fringilla lacus volutpat quis. Nam iaculis nisl vitae mauris scelerisque, eget vulputate purus aliquet. Nullam dictum nunc a enim tempus, et fermentum lectus tristique.
Nulla quis mattis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut a elit nec ipsum accumsan cursus. Nunc vitae lorem a tellus aliquam luctus eu eget turpis. Vivamus dapibus elementum imperdiet. Nullam facilisis mauris ac tellus fringilla volutpat. Sed elementum ligula dolor, vitae tincidunt ligula ultrices in.
   </p>
```

Comment: I don't really think theres any reason to float the text in the media query. Adding unnecessary floats can cause layout issues down the road and force the use of extra "clear float" classes.

Comment: Thank you! That worked as well. Any idea how I can get rid of the ugly extra space after breakdown? The text is centered, but the image is off to the left, leaving extra space.